# Bootstrap modal forces scroll to top

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm currently trying to implement a feed of posts, where clicking on a post would open a modal. I'm using angular as a frontend framework and decided to use the bootstrap modal, since it works well with angular. Problem is, that the modal forces the body to scroll to top when showing. This is ofcourse not ideal when scrolling through a feed.

The css line below is the culprit. Why this causes the problem to occur, i do not know, but i kind of need the scrollbar to be always showing. Loaading of dynamic content would otherwise make my layout jump around.

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Removing this line is fine right now, but i need to find a fix soon, as the layout would jump horizontally when loading new content, if the scrollbar is not always visible and then suddenly appearing. Does anyone have any clue as to why this causes the problem, and how i can possibly fix it?

Comment: Please provide some more code. This is not the default behavior of the bootstrap modal (as you can see here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the modal is the problem. Make sure your modal or its outer-most container has `position: fixed`, as it sounds like it is disrupting the flow of the `<body>` element.